# Android Service doesnt restart by itself

Tags: android

In my application I have an activity and a service (extends IntentService ). the service's onStartCommand looks like below

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

My onHandleIntent method:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
   while(continueLoop){ //continueLoop is controlled by the Binder
          //Do stuff
   }
}
```

I also bind to the service from activity, so I can break the infinite loop. I started the app and it's service, and then started other applications, after a while my Activity got stopped and destroyed, so is my Service. When I close the other applications using task manager , the service doesn't start by itself.

I waited and then launched my app, as soon as activity is launched service also started. I thought the android system will restart the service automatically when memory is available. Am I missing something or should i wait longer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I also bind to the service from activity" -- but do you ever call `startActivity()`?

Comment: Do you mean startService? I call it and then bind to the service to control it.

Answer (score 1):

If you read this [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) you'll see that

> onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
>   You should not override this method for your IntentService.

Instead

> The IntentService class exists to simplify this pattern and take care of the mechanics. **To use it, extend IntentService and implement onHandleIntent(Intent).**

Answer (score 0):

Per the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) documentation:

> Clients send requests through `startService(Intent)` calls; the service is started as needed, handles each `Intent` in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

If you are binding to the Service and/or controlling the lifecycle of the service yourself, then you should use a `Service` and not an `IntentService`.